# jQuery + Stop + Callback Functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

From what I understand using `.stop()` will prevent the callback functions to fire, right?

Unfortunately, it seems that this does not work in my current script:

```
newSubMenu.stop().slideToggle(250, function() {
  newSubMenu.css('visibility', 'visible').addClass('open');
});
```

The animation now stops when double clicking, but `newSubMenu` still gets the class `open` and I cant figure out why.

The goal I am trying to achieve, is to NOT apply the class `open` until the animation is complete.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/stop/):

> When `.stop()` is called on an element, the currently-running animation (if any) is immediately stopped. … Callback functions are not called.

Callback functions *are* called if the third argument to `stop()` is `true`.

In the code you provide, though, the callback will run because you're stopping already running animations, not the `slideToggle()` animation which has yet to run when `stop()` is called.

Here is a [working example showing the callback being stopped](http://jsfiddle.net/Dg3yC/).

Comment: @Andrej I've edited my answer to to add a link to a working example showing the callback being stopped.

Comment: thanks for your effort, however me being a newbie I cant really figure out how to use this in my script. Is it too much if I asked you to try to show me how this would be implemented in my script? I tried to put `newSubMenu.stop();` in front of the `slideToggle()` function, but obviously it doesnt work that way. Just like this: http://jsfiddle.net/Dg3yC/1/

Comment: I figured it out :) I am not even sure if its because of your answer, but the effect is now exactly what I wanted. It was simple: instead of calling stop at the `slideToggle()`, I am doing it now on the `.css()` like this: `newSubMenu.stop().css('visibility', 'visible').addClass('open');` and by doing so, double clicking will just open the menu once. And thats exactly what I was looking for :) I am gonna mark your anser anyways, since it pointed me in the right direction! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

To see why this happens, you have to understand, what toggle does.
Everytime you click, the `slideToggle` gets itself the information to `slideDown` or `slideUp`.

The conclusion is: everytime the toggle is complete, your function will be called and your newSubMenu gets the `visibility:visible` *style*, plus the class `"open"` if it doesn't exist.

```
Click-> Stop all animations on element -> toggle slide -> call/excecute function
```

Answer (score 1):

`.stop()` can be used to stop currently running animations. Once the animation has been completed the callback will be executed. In order to stop the current animation and avoid the callback being called you need to do something like this;

```
newSubMenu.mouseover(function(){
    newSubMenu.slideToggle(250, function(){
        $(this).css('visibility', 'visible').addClass('open');
    });
}).dblclick(function(){

    // this will stop the execution of the .slideToggle animation
    // whitch will prevent the callback from being executed
    newSubMenu.stop();

});
```

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/k5gED/1/)

Comment: This works, but I dont want it to slide on hover, but on click. And changing [your example](http://jsfiddle.net/k5gED/2/) from `mouseover` to `click`, it will not stop :/ I probably just dont get the idea behind your answer, but simply using it in my script wont work.

Comment: @Andrej you have to keep in mind that when you are double clicking you also trigger a click event, I will make an example in a sec

Comment: yeah i figured out thats the reason why it doesnt work :) But you dont have to make another example, since I was able to solve the issue myself thanks to all of your comments, that pointed me in the right direction!!

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has added an "always" callback in version 1.8:

> **always**
>
> *Type: Function( Promise animation, Boolean jumpedToEnd )*
>
> A function to be called when the animation completes or stops without
>   completing (its Promise object is either resolved or rejected).
>   (version added: 1.8)

URL: http://api.jquery.com/animate/

This will be fired always, if an animation is regularly done or if you interupt it with `stop()`.